# My website does not have Site Title

Tags: php

I used seo validator to check my website, but it says my website does not have site title. I have these header codes below:

```
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="RR4KnVDyxKEeBxQg8Qwphb0E2RuBTxVE3y-NrLS_tsw" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> &raquo; <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <meta name="Description" content="Davao Property For Sale is the desired partner of Filipino families in finding and owning a HOME in Davao City, Philippines every step of the way." />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="Davao City, real estate, House for sale, rush house, brand new, ready for occupancy, Davao Property" />
```

Please help!

Comment: Do any of those functions actually echo anything?

Comment: if you view the page source, is, `<title>` populated??

Comment: care to give a link to view this page?

Comment: the link is davaopropertyforsale.com

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<title>
<?php 

    $title = bloginfo('name');

    if ( is_single() ) { 
       $title .= '&raquo;'; 
    } 

    $title .= wp_title(); 

    echo $title;
  ?>
 </title>
```

The idea is to use the variable $title to concatenate your title and finally write it with function echo.

Comment: I think you want quotes around `&raquo;`

Comment: i did write the codes above and got double site title..see davaopropertyforsale.com

Comment: I see "Davao Property For Sale - Apply For Home Loan Now!" on Home, and "Blogs Archives - Davao Property For Sale - Apply For Home Loan Now!" on Blog... and "Ilumina Estates Archives - Davao Property For Sale - Apply For Home Loan Now!", please show me which part is duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

```
<title><?php echo bloginfo('name').(is_single()?' &raquo;':'').' '.wp_title() ?></title>
```

or

```
<title><?= bloginfo('name').(is_single()?' &raquo;':'').' '.wp_title() ?></title>
```

or

```
<?php $pageT = bloginfo('name');
if (is_single()) $pageT .= ' &raquo;';
$pageT .= ' ' . wp_title(); ?>
<title><?php echo $pageT ?></title>
```

There are some other possibilities to write this, though.